# How to change the alignment of the navigation bar in iOS in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I want to move the menu button to the right in RTL mode and vice versa, but it doesn't respond to the FlowDirection, I have had a similar problem in Android and I used a renderer:

```
class CustomNavigationPageRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.NavigationPageRenderer
{
    public CustomNavigationPageRenderer(Context context) : base(context) { }
    private static Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar GetToolbar() => (CrossCurrentActivity.Current?.Activity as MainActivity)?.FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);

    protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
    {
        base.OnLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
        var actionBar = GetToolbar();
        actionBar.LayoutDirection = Helpers.Settings.Lang == "ar" ? LayoutDirection.Rtl : LayoutDirection.Ltr;
    }

}
```

but don't know how to make this in iOS, also I want to change the `Menu` title.

[image]

So how to use the navigation renderer in iOS?

EDIT

MasterDetailpage (MainPage.Xaml):

```
<MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <views:MenuPage/>
</MasterDetailPage.Master>

<MasterDetailPage.Detail>
    <NavigationPage>
        <x:Arguments>
            <views:AllOrdersPage/>
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Detail>
```

cs:

```
 public MainPage()
        {
            FlowDirection = Settings.FlowDirection;
            InitializeComponent();
            MasterBehavior = MasterBehavior.SplitOnPortrait;    
        }
```

Comment: Xamarin forms version is latest right?

Comment: Yes: 3.5.0.169047

Comment: Oh, there's a newer version

Comment: Update to that and yeah do one thing add your masterdetail code aswell

Comment: updated both of them

Comment: What do you have in `Settings.FlowDirection` when you execute this?

Comment: FlowDirection.RightToLeft

Comment: Have you added the languages in Info.plist?

Comment: yes: `<key>CFBundleLocalizations</key>
 <array>
  <string>ar</string>
  <string>en</string>
 </array>`

Comment: Can you try manually setting it to right to left in MasterDetail XAML and then setting the localization to ar?

Comment: Take a look at https://blog.xamarin.com/right-to-left-localization-xamarin-forms/